# Android Studio 3.0 mksdcard error when creating AVD

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have an issue in creating new AVD in android studio 3.0.

error is

> Invalid argument size '124M'
>
> mksdcard: create a blank FAT32 image to be used with the Android emu
>   usage: mksdcard [-l label]
>
> if  is a simple integer, it specifies a size in bytes   if
>    is an integer followed by 'K', it specifies a size in Ki   if
>    is an integer followed by 'M', it specifies a size in Mi   if
>    is an integer followed by 'G', it specifies a size in Gi
>
> Minimum size is 9M. The Android emulator cannot use smaller images.
>   Maximum size is 1099511627264 bytes, 1073741823K, 1048575M or 1023G

The same error happens if I use mksdcard from CMD.

AS is installed on win7.

Comment: Could you share your command?

Comment: mksdcard -l mysdcard 124M mysdcard.img

Comment: Which specifications you are using to create your AVD?

Comment: I tried different specs, but as I mentioned before problem is that mksdcard doesn't work, maybe some libraries are missed, but I didn't find any mistakes in logs....

Comment: I created img file on another pc with mksdcard and used it on pc with problem - AVD created successfully. But in common the issue is still unsolved